# Saving answers from different communities into the same List

Tags: feature-request, saves

While searching about a particular subject, I often find answers that address my concerns in different communities of the parent platform. As such, I was wondering if there was a way to save these answers in the same list, since by default lists created in one community aren't shown when connecting to another.

Comment: so basically global saves?

Comment: That's one way to say it.

Comment: Browser bookmarks would collect all of these in one place. The difference being that there wouldn't be live updates. In general, SO, the company, has been *very* resistant to adding features, or even just simple options, which span across multiple SE sites.